# Dart/Flutter: URI/HTTPClient - disable automatic escaping of %

Tags: flutter, http, dart, uri

I have a problem with the dart/flutter URI implementation.
% is automatically replaced by %25.

i want to access the following URL:
`http://some.domain/json.php?key=%DF`  [%DF=ß in ASCII/latin1]

the code:

```
    final uri = Uri.http('some.domain', 'json.php', {'key': 'ß'});
```

results in
`http://some.domain/json.php?key=%C3%9F`    [ß in UTF-8]

when trying

```
    final uri = Uri.http('some.domain', 'json.php', {'key': '%DF'});
```

it results in:
`http://some.domain/json.php?key=%25DF` [% automatically escaped to %25]

when trying explicit encoding:

```
    final uri = Uri.http('some.domain', 'json.php',
        {'key': Uri.encodeQueryComponent('ß', encoding: latin1)});
```

it results in:
`http://some.domain/json.php?key=%25DF` [% automatically escaped to %25]

How can I disable the automatic encoding of % to %25?!

any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `queryParameters` parameter of the `Uri.http` constructor expects an unencoded map of data that it encodes using it's own standard, since you need to use another standard for this case might be better to use the `Uri` constructor and build your own query string and pass to the `query` parameter.

Something like this should do the trick:

```dart
final uri = Uri(
  scheme: 'http',
  host: 'some.domain',
  path: 'json.php',
  query: 'key=${Uri.encodeQueryComponent('ß', encoding: latin1)}'
);
```

Comment: YES YES YES! :)
Thanks very much for this fast support - IT WORKS. I debugged 2 hours with a short deep dive into the dart core code, to see that there is enforced encoding in `queryParameters`

that this circumvents the issue is great!

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the encoded URL, just use [`Uri.parse`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Uri/parse.html):

```dart
var uri = Uri.parse('http://some.domain/json.php?key=%DF');
```

`Uri.parse` is far simpler and far less error-prone than attempting to use `Uri.http`/`Uri.https` directly.  Avoid using those, and complain to anyone who instructed you to use them.