# Flutter: Trying to make a Uri with `Uri.http` to localhost: Why does it seem not allowing numbers in baseurl?

Tags: flutter, dart

Relevant code:

```dart
  String _baseUrl = 'localhost:3001/api/v1';
  String _path = 'items';
  Uri uri = Uri.http(_baseUrl, _path);
```

The error occurs on the call to Uri.http. Here's the error:

```
FormatException (FormatException: Invalid radix-10 number (at character 1)
3001/api/v1
^
```

Comment: Please just use [`Uri.parse`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67540701/) instead.  Why do so many people insist on using `Uri.http`/`Uri.https`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is misleading. The problem doesn't have to do with the `3001` portion, instead `Uri.http` is expecting the base_url to be more, well, basic.

Changing the code to this resolved the problem:

```dart
  String _baseUrl = 'localhost:3001';
  String _path = 'api/v1/items';
  Uri uri = Uri.http(_baseUrl, _path);
```

*note: if using a device (android or ios), replace localhost with the specific address, see:* [How to point to localhost:8000 with the Dart http package in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47372568/how-to-point-to-localhost8000-with-the-dart-http-package-in-flutter)